# How does Facebook know my credit card number?

Tags: facebook

I just looked at boosting a post on [one of my Facebook pages](https://www.facebook.com/humansofnewtownwgtn/).

And they already had a credit card number for me.

I'm pretty sure I haven't given them my credit card details before, is there another reason they could have my credit card number?

For example, I do use Gmail to log in to it, and Gmail has my credit card number.

Comment: Have you connected Facebook to PayPal, perhaps when you Boosted another page?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is you gave Facebook your CC number at some point.

Second most likely is you gave your CC number to a company that belongs to Facebook.

No external company, like Google, would share your payment information with Facebook without your explicit permission. There are very specific laws and regulations around even storing a credit card number let alone sharing it with a 3rd party.

Answer (score 1):

If you either paid for something or donated to a charity that posted on and was processed via Facebook, then whatever form of electronic payment you used would be stored by FB, and is accessible to FB Gameroom. It is disconcerting, and, probably, shouldn't even be stored by Facebook - - even for transactions paid to FB, such as to boost traffic to your FB group/page - - but, it is easy enough to remove: Go to https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=payments&section=settings *(in case this changes, click the arrow/carat at the top right of the FB blue bar, then click 'Settings,' then click 'Payments')* and delete any payment information.